# ¿Cómo puedo disminuir el tiempo de carga de mi web?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Buenos días, quisiera saber cómo puedo reducir el tiempo de carga de mi web, la web tiene una radio.

```
<div class="reproductor">
    <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
      <source src="http://109.167.24.228:8888/stream" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Este es el código de la radio que tengo en la web pero ralentiza mucho el tiempo de carga ¿cómo puedo hacer para bajar el tiempo de carga?

Comment: Te dejo un enlace que igual puede ayudarte a entender mejor como funciona el tema multimedia. http://www.grc.upv.es/docencia/tdm/practicas/P3.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo creo que poco puedes hacer. Al implementar el stream desde otro pc, eso requiere la petición, respuesta, carga etc... En cuanto al resto, si ordenas css, intenta comprimir el JS (me refiero a usar solo lo necesario).
Luego otra cosa que se me ocurre, que igual el stream tiene demasiada calidad y por eso tarda tanto. Poco mas se me ocurre.
Luego también se me ocurre, que al enviar el stream, que la resolución base sea 320x178, a lo que lo vas a mostrar en la pagina, así reducirás algo también.

Comment: Al ser un stream suponía que no podía hacer muchas cosas para mejorar el tiempo de carga. Muchas gracias de todos modos

Comment: mira lo ultimo que edite, cambia la resolucion base del stream a la que lo muestras en la pagina. Asi te ira mas fluido

Comment: Ahora pruebo a ver, es que tarda 4.75 segundos en cargar y si le quito el steam va volado, pero necesito ponerlo porque es una web para una radio la cual quiere una radio en la web

Comment: Prueba eso, porque si lo estas enviando en una resolucion 1280x720(ejemplo), y la muestras a la cuarta parte... no tiene mucho sentido. asi es lo unico que se me ocurre

Comment: Muchas gracias, he podido bajarlo un par de segundos, ahora tarda 3.43

Answer (score 4):

Si utilizas jquery, creo que podrias hacer algo como lo siguiente:

html:

```
<div class="reproductor">
    <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176"></video>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myVideo')
      .append('<source src="http://109.167.24.228:8888/stream" type="video/mp4">')[0]
      .play();
```

});

La idea es que cuando la pagina este cargada, se lance el document.ready,  te añada el source del video y luego se ejecute el play.

He hecho este ejemplo, pero me da timeout con tu url de stream (supongo que sea de un servidor propio).

```
<html>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<h1>hola radio</h1>
    <div class="reproductor">
        <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176"></video>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myVideo')
          .append('<source src="http://109.167.24.228:8888/stream" type="video/mp4">')[0]
          .play();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: http://109.167.24.230:8888/stream es que esta mal la ruta, seria esta

Comment: ahora intento hacerlo con Jquery

Comment: buena manera de lograrlo gracias