# addEventLstener no funciona bien

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que que quiero es que el vídeo se reproduzca en un navegador de android y de la única manera que me funciona hasta ahorita es con el evento que ya tengo que es con "click" pero lo que quiero es que se reproduzca cuando inicie la pagina ya intente con load y onload

Este es mi video

```
 <video id="video" class="slider-video" width="100%" height="auto" `preload="" autoplay="autoplay" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; " poster="imgs/video.jpg" >`
                <source src="imgs/video.webm">
                <source src="imgs/pruebai.webm type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>

 </video>
```

Este es mi script

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
    window.addEventListener("click",function(){
  video.play();
    },false);
  });
```

Comment: Echa un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76263/cómo-puedo-disminuir-el-tiempo-de-carga-de-mi-web/76276#76276,  aunque la solución es con jquery, puede darte una idea de como ejecutarlo después de la carga de la web

Comment: ya lo intente pero me sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con [EventTarget.dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), este dispara el evento asociado al elemento `html`, en el siguiente ejemplo disparo en el evento `onClick` asociado al elemento `<button id="alert">`.

Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("alert").addEventListener("click",getAlert);

function getAlert(){
 alert("Hola");
}
// Aquí disparo el evento onClick asociado al <button id="alert">
document.getElementById("alert").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

```html
<button id="alert">Alert("Hola");</button>
```

Para versiones Anteriores a **IE9** debes usar el método [EventTarget.fireEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/fireEvent).

Si deseas una solucione realmente facil y compatible con todos los exploradores, te recomiendo uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("alert").addEventListener("click",getAlert);

function getAlert(){
 alert("Hola");
}
// Aquí disparo el evento onClick asociado al <button id="alert">
$("#alert").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="alert">Alert("Hola");</button>
```